# ZF2 already active query prevents execution

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I have something like the following, in a function that deletes both the files and db entries:

```
$adapter = $this->getAdapter();
$query = $adapter->query("call find_results_by_job_id(?)", array($jobId));
$items = array();
while (($current = $query->current()) !== false)
{
    $id = $current['id'];
    $items[] = $id;
    $query->next();
}
$this->deleteFromDataStore($items);
$result = $adapter->query("call delete_results_by_job_id(?)", array($jobId), \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

(Some of that might not look like the best way to do it, because I simplified it for this example)

I'm getting this error on the last line: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.`

I'm assuming that the problem is because the query/adapter hasn't closed the connection from iterating results yet when I try to execute another statement. If that is the case, how can reuse the adapter, or close the query, or whatever I have to do before the last line?

The strange part is that code following almost exactly this same pattern works in another method.

---

Answer:

When using the PDO driver, `$query->getDataSource()->getResource()->closeCursor();` fixes it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are using an [unbuffered query in MySQL](http://php.net/manual/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php).

If it is so, you will either have to turn buffering on or break execution of previous query which seems to hang?

Something like `$query->close()`

EDIT:

If `$query` is instance of `StatementInterface`, then there is `getResource()` which returns `mysqli_stmt` and you can call [`close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) on it.

EDIT2: (to incorporate final resolution)

In case it uses PDO, you can get `PDOStatement` and call `closeCursor()`

Comment: Yes, something like $query->close() would be useful, if it existed. Sadly, I can't find anything like that for the resultset object or db adapter

Comment: $query is an instance of \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet. It has a `getDataSource()` method, which returns a \Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result, which does have a `getResource()` method, but it returns a PDOStatement. Neither of those has a `close()` method.

Comment: @rwilson04 in that case I looked at wrong driver, for PDO you should have [`PDOStatement::closeCursor(void)`](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.closecursor.php)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the result of a query in your hands and you dont know whether it is a ResultSet or a Result, the following will do the job.
Tested as of Zend Framework 3.

```
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
...

public function closeResult( $result )
{
    if( is_a($result, ResultSet::class) )
    {
        $stmt = $result->getDataSource()->getResource();
    }
    else
    {
        $stmt = $result->getResource();
    }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->adapter
->query($sql)
->execute()
->getResource()
->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!

Comment: answer is unrelated to the original question.